# Steps to prepare Play app for production

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm ready to deploy my app and I'm wondering what steps I need to take to get it ready for production? I've seen the docs over @ http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production but I need some more info. I'm currently using an in-memory database. Obviously, I want to change that. I plan on deploying to Heroku and I've tested that with my app as-is..in-memory DB and all. 
If I configure a different DB, do I need to have drivers for that installed locally as well? Also, the docs mention changing the config for prod mode. I also heard/read something about some play staging command?

Sorry for the incoherent question, but I could use some general guidance on best steps/practices for preparing and deploying production app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the page for the Todo List App? The section "Deploying to Heroku" on this page http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTodoList has how to use postgresql.

Comment: Thanks for that link. I've had an issue with the procfile. Heroku always reports that is mis-cased..says to change it to Procfile with a capital P which I've done, but it still reports that. What does root of app mean? The root folder or in /app Either way it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Fixed procfile issue. Different question: those docs don't show how to change conf file. I still have db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play" in there currently. How do I change it to support postgresql?

Comment: The values are overridden by ones in the Procfile "-Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver". It's not a good idea to hardcode the values like url in conf for security and context-changing reasons. Heroku also allows you to  set the values later through its console. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars